# PHP shell_exec() sometimes doesn't work

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

I have a PHP script that performs an import of data from a vendor partner. One of the things that it needs to do is to call another script via shell_exec() that then processes an image file and uploads it to an Amazon S3 bucket. I'm watching the output from this script in a terminal right now, and after a while I see a series of messages along the lines of:

`Warning: shell_exec(): Unable to execute 'php -f /path/to/second/script.php /path/to/image/to/process.jpg' in /path/to/this/script.php on line 453`

The weird thing is that this same script is called multiple times in this script and works to begin with, and then stops. It's called from other scripts as well and works fine in those. When I copy the command that it couldn't run and paste it in myself it always works. Clearly PHP is capable of running it sometimes.

I've put a memory usage echo on each line as it runs, and I've seen it as high as 148MB while working correctly, and as low as 77MB when it's erroring. (this is in the main script, not the secondary script that cannot be run). The memory usage seems to get lower and lower as the errors start coming in. The first time I noticed it was around 88MB and then it dropped to 85MB, 81MB and then to 77MB.

I'm unclear on what might be causing the script to sometimes work and sometimes not. Last time I checked it wasn't possible for PHP to decide whether it can be bothered or not, and it doesn't get worn out, so why does it work fine for ages (I'm talking hundreds, if not thousands of successful downloads) and then suddenly it stops working. It's not that it's trying to process images that couldn't be downloaded, as there's a condition in the script that prevents that and I often see a load of `image does not exist` even while it's failing processing the rest. I've ended up having to write another script that runs back through and processes all missing images again afterwards.

ANY thoughts would be really gratefully received!

By the way, this is running on a large AWS EC2 instance with the Amazon Linux OS. We're running PHP5.3

Comment: By the way, I have tried changing the command to be `/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/second/script.php /path/to/image/to/process.jpg` which also works from the CLI, but the script still has the same issue. PHP Safe Mode is off

Comment: Have you solved this one? I also have this problem on Amazon centos 7.

Comment: HI @Silko. I never did, no. I left that role a few months after I posted so it hasn't been a problem for me since :)

Comment: I solved mine. I found out that I had some disallowed characters (like +, /) in the arguments I have used in shell_exec. When those characters were used shell_exec failed. Maybe this would help someone :)

Comment: Good to know. I don't think that was the case with ours since running the command manually sorted it, but I'm sure that could still be useful to some

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue and I found that /paht/to/php was /usr/bin/php5